# Generalized barycentric coordinates with Lagrange property

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, coordinate-systems, affine-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Let $p : n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be a sequence of points. Let $\lambda : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a [generalized barycentric coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Generalized_barycentric_coordinates) (GBCS) with respect to $p$. That is,
\begin{align*}
    1 &= \sum_{i \in n} \lambda(x)_i \\
    x &= \sum_{i \in n} \lambda(x)_i p_i
\end{align*}
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. [*Affine generalised barycentric coordinates*](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~waldron/Preprints/Barycentric/barycentric.pdf) by Shayne Waldron defines a GBCS with nice properties by imposing the additional constraint of minimizing the $L_2$ norm
\begin{align*}
    \|\lambda(x)\|_2^2 = \sum_{i \in n} |\lambda(x)_i|^2
\end{align*}
at each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. However, this GBCS doesn't satisfy the Lagrange property, namely that
\begin{align*}
    \lambda(p_j)_i = \delta_{ji}
\end{align*}
for all $i, j \in n$. Is there a "nice" continuous GBCS which satisfies this property?

I think adding the constraint of minimizing the $L_0$ "norm" (i.e. maximizing sparsity) guarantees the Lagrange property, but does it guarantee uniqueness everywhere else?

[*Generalized barycentric coordinates in computer graphics and computational mechanics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VmpQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kai Hormann and N. Sukumar lists (on Table 1.1, page 15) 3 methods that are defined with respect to sets of scattered points, as opposed to just convex polygons or arbitrary simple polygons:

- Affine coordinates (Waldron).
- [Sibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation) natural neighbor coordinates.
- Laplace coordinates.

Of these, only the last two satisfy the Lagrange property, and they require the computation of [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). Another approach I can think of is to construct the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) of the point set and then use ordinary barycentric coordinates on the triangle a point falls inside of.